# Visual studio smooth PageUp/PageDown?

Tags: visual-studio, text-editor

I find the problem with PageUp/PageDown in Visual Studio (and in most editors for that matter) is that it navigates one complete page at a time, and does so instantly. Doing it multiple times you will eventually lose the notion of where you are in the code and lose track where you came from.

My questions:

- Is there any way I could modify PageUp/PageDown to jump half a page?
- Is there any way I could make PageUp/PageDown scroll 'smoothly' and not instantly? (think Lerp)

To my knowledge this doesn't exist out of the box, and I couldn't find any plugins to do it.

**EDIT:** I do **NOT** use the mouse when programming. Suggesting to use the mouse wheel or a 'touch screen' defeats the purpose of staying in the main row.

Comment: Use your mouse wheel.

Comment: Get a touch screen laptop

Comment: Hope you guys are trolling. I never touch the mouse while programming. I have everything wired to keyboard shortcuts. Mouse slows me down dramatically...

Comment: Is it possible to write a VS plugin to do it? If so, what's the relevant API I should be looking at?

Comment: Did you Google Visual Studio smooth scrolling?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman yes and they're all mouse plugins, nothing related to pageup/pagedown.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my fork of the [fork](https://github.com/pragmatrix/SmoothScroll) of [SmoothScroll](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lkytal.SmoothScroll) extension:

https://github.com/monoblaine/SmoothScroll

## Preview

[image: Smooth page scrolling]

## Configuration (only page scrolling)

[image: Extension configuration]

## Description

Normally, it supports scroolling the editor smoothly using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Wheel</kbd> but I don't use the mouse during coding, either. I use the numpad keys to send wheel events through [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

You can use the following script to send the keyboard & mouse event necessary to create a smooth page scroll using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>NumpadUp</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>NumpadClear</kbd> hotkeys:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe devenv.exe
    !NumpadUp::Send {Blind}{WheelUp}
    !NumpadClear::Send {Blind}{WheelDown}
#IfWinActive
```